# asking three questions to my japanese teacher in sonkeigo

Tags: keigo, sonkeigo

I need to ask three questions to my Japanese teacher as part of my oral examination. Since we studied it, I need to use sonkeigo but I'm unsure whether some of these questions may be inappropriate and I have doubts regarding how grammatically correct they might be.

- もし1日だけ億万長者になれたら、何のことをなさいますか。

Can I say なさりたいですか? and would だったら be too informal as a hypothesis, given that I'm talking to a teacher?

- 今までにいただいた最高のプレゼントは何でしょうか。 (Idk wheter to use プレゼントの中で..)
- 過去に戻ることができなら、何かを変更なさいますか。

I wanted to ask if ''you could go back to the past, what would you change?''.　Alternatively: is 変える too literal of a translation?

Comment: Due to the [no translation rule](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se/799#799), I guess it's better to split questions so that each question asks one specific point; There is no strict standard, but as it is, it may look like a proofreading request. From next time, or if you still have doubts after my answer/comments, you can delete this question and post new ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think having such a conversation already indicates a friendly enough relationship. As such, using sonkeigo in those sentences sounds like a register mismatch to me (though it's not impossible). Simple です/ます（丁寧語） should be enough, practically speaking.

The following are more like comments, but hope it helps.

> もし1日だけ億万長者になれたら、何のことをなさいますか。

- なれたら in the condition is fine; I don't really think of a way to make it sonkeigo. 何のこと means *about what*; you should use 何をなさいますか (what would you do?) or どうなさいますか.

> 今までにいただいた最高のプレゼントは何でしょうか。

- いただく cannot be used to refer to the action of someone for whom sonkeigo is used. [This](https://biz.trans-suite.jp/4483) lists お受け取りになる as a sonkeigo for もらう. So technically, it can be 今までにお受け取りになった最高のプレゼントは何でしょうか(or 何でございますか) - but it sounds just too polite unless you are a (real) maid or butler or something...

> 過去に戻ることができ**た/る**なら、何かを変更なさいますか。

何かを means *(change) something*, so as it is, it means *would you change anything?*. For *what would you...*, you should use 何を変更なさいますか; Or 何をお変えになりますか. Either way, mostly because of the casualness of the question, using sonkeigo is particularly odd to me. Using again simple 何をなさいますか would be less odd.

Comment: thank u so much! this really helped me :))) also I got an A+ hehehe